# How can I debug issues with my SSD?

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

My computer has slowed to a crawl, and I'm pretty sure my SSD is the culprit. As of this morning, my OS takes forever to start up (20+ minutes to get to the Windows login). Ever since I installed the SSD I've had random slow downs where Windows freezes for several second before responding, once even leading to a BSOD about processor clock not responding in time.

The fact that it now takes forever to start and run is new as of a few hours ago, but the drive is a few weeks old now. I've got Samsung Magician (the SSD monitoring software that comes with the drive) and am trying to run some diagnostics, but it is taking a long time.

**What is a good way to debug and isolate issues with a SSD that I can employ?**

Some more details about my particular case:

- Drive is Samsung 840 SSD (520 gb)
- On Windows 7 64 bit
- OS was installed clean on this drive, and I can boot to my old OS if needed
- Drivers and firmware reporting as up to date on all pieces of hardware on the machine

Comment: Possible answer http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/275607-32-slow

Comment: Did you install the OS fresh or transfer it from another drive?

Comment: Installed fresh. Looks like my drive may have just had a hardware failure though, so that may have been the cause :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AHCI Mode**

Sata ports can usually be configured to **AHCI** or **IDE**. Make sure it is configured as AHCI

---

**Capacity**

All hard disks will slow considerably the closer they are to being full. Keep atleast 20% available free space.

---

**Run Checkdisk**
Solid State drives can get bad sectors just like normal hard drives. Run a checkdisk on the drive.

---

**TRIM Support**

It is very likely that TRIM is not enabled.

If you aren't familiar with TRIM, [checkout this article](http://solid-state-drive-review.toptenreviews.com/what-is-trim-support.html).

To see if TRIM is enabled, open up powershell, and enter the following command

```
fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

If it returns 1, that means TRIM is *disabled*. To enable TRIM, run the following command.

```
fsutil behavior set DisableDeleteNotify 0
```

---

**Check Alignment**

All drives newer than 2011 should ship with [4096 Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) size. [Verify that your block size](http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/checking_ssd_alignment) is 4096 or a number evenly divisible by 4096.

---

**AHCI Drivers**

The slow performance and blue screens could also be caused by having missing / outdated AHCI drivers installed. [(Source)](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1663139)
Go to your manufactures website, and download the latest AHCI drivers. It would be good to install the latest chipset drivers while you are at it.

---

**Disable Unneeded Services**

[These settings](http://www.maketecheasier.com/12-things-you-must-do-when-running-a-solid-state-drive-in-windows-7/2012/05/11) should be configured regardless if your SSD is running slowly or not. Things like the pagefile, system restore, and disk defragmentation should be adjusted for SSDs.

---

**Fresh Install**

If you have a spare hard drive, use a program like norton ghost, or acronis disk utility to clone the drive. Perform a fresh install and see if the problem goes away. It could be a corrupted installation of windows.

---

**Resources**

http://blogs.computerworld.com/ssd/20839/windows-7-and-ssds-3-things-look-out
http://solid-state-drive-review.toptenreviews.com/what-is-trim-support.html
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/298293-32-slowing-down

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, TRIM support is enabled on my machine already.

Comment: @Ktash I've updated the answer with a few more things to try. My money is on a Missing AHCI driver, or a corrupted windows install.